# Editing RichTextBox from another method

Tags: c#

I've got a little problem, experimenting with C#.
I have a **RichTextBox** which after I click a button, it edits it with `results.Text = "test";`.

However, in the `button_Click` method, I call another method, let's name it `X`, which has the same syntax `results.Text = "john doe";`. 
This doesn't work. I've tried changing Modifiers to Public for both controls (buttons, richtextbox), but no luck.

I know I'm missing something so basic, but I can't seem to find it. Below is the example code:

```
  public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 obj = new Form1();
        results.Text = "nice"; //this works
        obj.X(a, b, c);
    }
```

Now, the method X (which is called from above method):

```
public void X(double x, double y, double z)
{
results.Text = "john doe" //doesn't work
}
```

Any additional explanation why this occurs? Thanks.

Comment: Can Form1 acess this result object ?? Have you taken care of the scope of result ??

Comment: Is the control named "results" on Form1? You are creating a new form in the button click, are you creating the same form again?

Comment: Btw: Modifying the Text property will mess with any proir formatting. Always use the RTB methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling this code from a button on your form, right? Then you should not create a new form. Simply remove the following line:

```
   Form1 obj = new Form1();
```

and change the following line:

```
X(a, b, c); // without 'obj' in front
```

Comment: Exactly. It works as expected.
Can't mark as answer right now due to system security I guess, but another question if you don't mind, how can I add text to the same RichTextBox, without replacing it? I've got multiple `results.Text` and on the RichTextBox only the last one appears.

Comment: You can use AppendText(text) in your RichEdit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the `X` procedure independant from the calling form (either Form1, Form0 or any other Form) you could declare it as such:

```
public void X(RichTextBox sender, double x, double y, double z) {
   sender.text = "john doe" //it will always work
}
```

and it gets called in this way:

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 obj = new Form1();
    results.Text = "nice"; //this works
    obj.X(results, a, b, c);
}
```

You could even make this code `static` but I guess it would depend on your implementation details.

As said it is not clear if your `Form1` is the same form as the one hosting the button. If so, you should avoid recreating it again by deleting the line `Form1 obj = new Form1();` and just calling `X(a, b, c)` without adding the `RichTextBox` parameter to it.